# Best practice to inherit value from class?

Tags: c#

I would like to create a collectionbase class construction like this:

What is the best practice to reach (int NeedThisValue) in all items, what was added by this class?

```
public class SDataCollection : CollectionBase
{
    public SDataCollection()
    {
    }

    #region Properties
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets/Sets value for the item by that index
    /// </summary>
    public SData this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return (SData)this.List[index];
        }
        set
        {
            this.List[index] = value;
        }
    }

    public int NeedThisValue { get; private set; }

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    public int IndexOf(SData sDataItem)
    {
        if (sDataItem != null)
        {
            return base.List.IndexOf(sDataItem);
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public int Add(SData sDataItem)
    {
        if (sDataItem != null)
        {
            return this.List.Add(sDataItem);
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public void Remove(SData sDataItem)
    {
        this.InnerList.Remove(sDataItem);
    }

    public void AddRange(SDataCollection collection)
    {
        if (collection != null)
        {
            this.InnerList.AddRange(collection);
        }
    }

    public void Insert(int index, SData sDataItem)
    {
        if (index <= List.Count && sDataItem != null)
        {
            this.List.Insert(index, sDataItem);
        }
    }

    public bool Contains(SData sDataItem)
    {
        return this.List.Contains(sDataItem);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question - what needs to access `NeedThisValue`? Is it users (consumers) of the `SDataCollection` class, or items that you add via the indexer?

Comment: The items, what has been added via indexer...

Answer (score 1):

if you want that property to be accessed only by subclasses of SDataCollection, use the access modifier

> protected

if you want that property to be accessed by all other classes, use the access modifier

> public

if you do not want that property to be accessed by anything but SDataCollection, use

> private

this is <strike>C#</strike> Object Oriented 101.

Comment: Due to the updated info left by the OP in the comments, this answer doesn't address the question. He wants to access `NeedThisValue` from the data items.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to access from all CData items the value of the corresponding NeedThisValue property.
Usually in these cases I set a refernce of the parent on each item.
On the CData class you can crete a property like:

```
internal SDataCollection Parent { get; set; }
```

Then you casn set/unset the Parent by overriding OnInsert/OnRemove/OnSet/OnClear. You must problably check if the item is attached by one and only one collection.

In any case I try to avoid these scenarios. Often there are some better approach, but I don't know your exact problem.

Comment: I try to create an architecture where is an instantiated class, what has a collectionbase inheritance. So I'm free to add items (instantiated classes) to it. The goal is if I call a method in item, than get the collection property value. I know, that may I can use constructors, or anything else, but I'm curious that is there any better solution to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is a bit unusual, but here goes....

I will assume that you want the `SData` object to access `NeedThisValue` on demand as its value may change over time - otherwise you could just create a property on `SData` and inject the value when the object is added to the collection.

I'm also going to discount injecting the value when the `SData` is *retrieved* from the collection, as the reference to the retrieved item may be long lived.

This means the only viable option left is to give each `SData` a reference to the parent collection class when you add it to the collection:

```
public class SData 
{
    public SDataCollection ParentCollection { get; set; }
}


public class SDataCollection : CollectionBase
{
    public int Add(SData sDataItem)
    {
        if (sDataItem != null)
        {
            sDataItem.ParentCollection = this;
            return this.List.Add(sDataItem);
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

When you use the `SData` item in some other code, you can then do this:

```
var thatMagicalValueYouWanted = myRandomSDataObject.ParentCollection.NeedThisValue;
```

Now I should point out that this is not a particularly good pattern to follow, but that's your call.

Comment: Than what is the good pattern for it? I only want, that the collection property value would be reachable via items. Once I instantiate a class what is inherit CollectionBase. Then I add to it items, and would like to only achieve that items what added through this collectionBase inherited class can reach the collection property value...

Comment: @user1692315 Ideally the collection items should have no knowledge or concept of the collection itself. If you elaborate on what the value `NeedToKnowThis` is for I may be able to suggest something.

Comment: Basically to create a 3d model class. This class can be instantiated depends, how many models I want to control. Let's call it Model class. This class has an IModelable property which was given via factory, this contains e.g. Weight. But I need additional compontents for each instantiated model class like Kinematic. So I found out, that I create a generic collection in the model class, and put these components in it. The problem is, that if I create a new components like Kinematic, it should knows the IModelable property value of the model class in order to compute e.g. the movements.